# Ubuntu Dual Boot Installation

Tags: dual-boot

Here is some information. The last line is the most important question.

I have an Asus X53S that has windows 7 installed. What I want to do is install Ubuntu onto my computer. The C drive currently has 69.9 GB of free space, and my D drive currently has 332 GB of free space.

Can I install Ubuntu onto this machine?

I want to install 100GB of VMWare onto the Ubuntu environment on this machine.

Therefore, I want to install the 1GB Ubuntu OS with 100GB of VMWare after. Can I do this on D drive? If not, is there a more efficient way to set up my computer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can install Ubuntu :)

You can boot the Ubuntu live CD/USB key and use the "gparted" tool to resize your D partition and after that, you will create an extended partition with the same tool and after that you can create a partition to use with Ubuntu, but before do this, is highly recommended to boot into windows and use his De-fragmentation tool on the D partition to prevent any data loss ;-)

See this post for more info: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd